# can i monitor four servers from one single net-data instance?

Tags: linux, monitoring, netdata

This is my one net data output

[image: This is my one net data output]

also i can  see other machinies this section

[image]

but i want to see other machinies as below picture and it will redirect detailed page when i click any machine

[image]

is that possible??
i searched on google but i am not able to find any answer.

i am working on linux machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to build a custom dashboard. And

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yournetdataip:19999/dashboard.js"></script>

        <div style="margin-right: 10px; width: 20%;"  
            class="netdata-container-gauge" 
            data-host="http://first-address:19999"
            data-netdata="system.cpu" 
            data-chart-library="gauge" 
            data-title="Server 1" data-units="%" 
            data-gauge-max-value="100" 
            data-width="20%" 
            data-after="-360" 
            data-points="360" 
            data-colors="#ff2600" 
            role="application">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-right: 10px; width: 20%;"  
            class="netdata-container-gauge" 
            data-host="http://second-address:19999"
            data-netdata="system.cpu" 
            data-chart-library="gauge" 
            data-title="Server 2" data-units="%" 
            data-gauge-max-value="100" 
            data-width="20%" 
            data-after="-360" 
            data-points="360" 
            data-colors="#ff2600" 
            role="application">
        </div>
```

This is will do what you wants.

Answer (score 9):

You need to build a custom dashboard.
They are explained here: https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/Custom-Dashboards

netdata ships with a few examples. The one you posted (the home page of netdata) is this file: https://github.com/firehol/netdata/blob/master/web/demosites.html

In general, custom dashboards require from you to write a `div` with some options, like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.netdata.ip:19999/dashboard.js"></script>

 <div data-netdata="netdata.requests"
      data-host="//london.my-netdata.io"
      data-title="EU - London"
      data-chart-library="gauge"
      data-decimal-digits="0"
      data-common-max="top-gauges"
      data-width="100%"
      data-after="-300"
      data-points="300"
      data-colors="#558855"
      ></div>
```

Once you add this in an html file, the `div` will be turned to a live netdata chart. You can host such a page anywhere you like (does not need to be served by the netdata web server).

Answer (score 0):

You can now do it with [Netdata Cloud](https://netdata.cloud)